# Magento 2 Order summary shows Zero

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm working in Magento 2.3 EE.

Very recently I got one issue related to order summary.

I have purchased one product and again order the same product, then the order summary shows 0. Please refer to the below image.
[image]
But this also happened very randomly.

I'm trying to figure out the root cause and solution for this issue.

Please give some suggestion to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you check private browser or check in console and log file.

Comment: Yes. I have checked in the private browser also. It returns the same and verified the log file and console, there is no error which is related to cart